# convert .NET generic List to F# list

Tags: c#, .net, f#, generic-list

Is there a built-in method to convert the .NET List<> into the F# list?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Try [**`List.ofSeq`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340325.aspx) in the `Microsoft.FSharp.Collections` namespace.

```
#                     List.ofSeq : seq<'T> -> 'T list
```

It's not specifically for `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`, but for `IEnumerable<T>` (`seq<'T>` in F#) types in general, so it should still work.

(It's also not strictly built into the F# language, but neither is `List<T>` built into C# or VB.NET. Those are all part of the respective standard libraries.)

Comment: I also noticed with the 2.0 compiler type inference the List<Something> on the right hand side shows up as a seq (or IEnumerable) on the left hand side. Pretty smart of those guys (+1)

Answer (score 15):

Given `IEnumerable<T> foo` you would do the following (in C#) to get an F# `list<T>`:

```
 var fsharpList = ListModule.OfSeq(foo);
```

`ListModule` refers to `Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.ListModule`, and is referred to as `List` from within F# itself.

Comment: There's no such thing as ListModule in F#

Comment: Its not specified if the question was about C# or F#. This code is in C#. There is a `ListModule` in F#. Its just called `list` in F#, so `list.ofSeq` in F# == `ListModule.OfSeq` in C#.